# About Firebase Connection

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-connection

I connected my project to firebase manually.
After connect i tried to initialize (DatabaseReference) variable but didn't get the variable.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy1lX.png)

Comment: We're missing quite a few details here, such as how you import the package and include the dependency. Also: please always post text as text, and not as a screenshot. "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if it's in the import ... ? If not you have to import it first.

`import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;`

`import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;`

---

If importing gives an error, check your build.gradle(Module:app). See if you have

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'`

inside dependencies. And also if you're using firebase storage, auth etc., you must have them there.